# java replace correct number into letter

Tags: java, numbers

Well, this is my first time get here.

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to replace number into letter. 
In this case, I need two steps.

First, convert letter to number. Second, restore number to word.

Words list: a = 1, b = 2, f = 6 and k = 11.

I have word: "b a f k"

So, for first step, it must be: "2 1 6 11"

Number "2 1 6 11" must be converted to "b a f k".

But, I failed at second step.

Code I've tried:

```
public class str_number {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String word = "b a f k";
    String number = word.replace("a", "1").replace("b","2").replace("f","6").replace("k","11");
    System.out.println(word);
    System.out.println(number);

    System.out.println();

    String text = number.replace("1", "a").replace("2","b").replace("6","f").replace("11","k");
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(text);

}
```

}

Result:

b a f  **k**

2 1 6 11

2 1 6 11

b a f **aa**

11 must be a word "k", but it's converted to "aa"

What is the right way to fix this?
Or do you have any other ways to convert letter to number and vice versa?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually not use replace in this case.

A more generic solution would be to simply convert it to a char and subtract the char a from it.

```
int n = word.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1;
```

This should return an int with the value you are looking for.

If you want this to be an string you can easily do

```
String s = Integer.parseInt(word.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1);
```

And as in your case you are doing a whole string looping through the length of it and changing all would give you the result

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i) != ' ') {            
        s = s + Integer.toString(word.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1) + " ";
    }
}
```

and then if you want this back to an String with letters instead

```
String text = "";
int temp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        text = text + String.valueOf((char) (temp + 'a' - 1));
        temp = 0;
    } else if {
        temp = (temp*10)+Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to write methods for conversion between number and letter format. I would write some code like this and use it generally instead of hard coding replace each time.

```
public class test {
    static ArrayList <String> letter = new ArrayList<String> ();
    static ArrayList <String> digit = new ArrayList<String> ();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createTable();
        String test="b a f k";
        String test1="2 1 6 11";
        System.out.println(letterToDigit(test));
        System.out.println(digitToLetter(test1));
    }

    public static void createTable()
    {
        //Create all your Letter to number Mapping here.
        //Add all the letters and digits
        letter.add("a");
        digit.add("1");

        letter.add("b");
        digit.add("2");

        letter.add("c");
        digit.add("3");

        letter.add("d");
        digit.add("4");

        letter.add("e");
        digit.add("5");

        letter.add("f");
        digit.add("6");

        letter.add("g");
        digit.add("7");

        letter.add("h");
        digit.add("8");

        letter.add("i");
        digit.add("9");

        letter.add("j");
        digit.add("10");

        letter.add("k");
        digit.add("11");

        letter.add("l");
        digit.add("12");

        letter.add("m");
        digit.add("13");

        letter.add("n");
        digit.add("14");

        letter.add("o");
        digit.add("14");

        letter.add("p");
        digit.add("15");
        //Carry so on till Z    
    }

    public static String letterToDigit(String input)
    {
        String[] individual = input.split(" ");
        String result="";

        for(int i=0;i<individual.length;i++){
            if(letter.contains(individual[i])){
                result+=Integer.toString(letter.indexOf(individual[i])+1)+ " "; 
            }   
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String digitToLetter(String input)
    {
        String[] individual = input.split(" ");
        String result="";

        for(int i=0;i<individual.length;i++){
            if(digit.contains(individual[i])){
                result+=letter.get(digit.indexOf(individual[i])) + " ";
            }   
        }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you. But, if I have another words, such as "b aa f k", it should be "2 11 6 11". Look, "aa" has same value number with "k". How to distinguish if "11" for "aa" and for "k"? The case also includes other letters which have two digits number for converting result.

Comment: Easiest way I could think now is as follows. 1) Check size of the individual array inside both methods (digitToLetter and letterToDigit) 2) If the size is two, you need to read this to another String Array and then do check contains method as shown above individually.

Comment: @Speaky: If you have a string "11", and no other info, you can't; the ambiguity makes it impossible to know for sure whether "aa" or "k" is correct.  You'd need either to provide some context (like the original string, though you could simply return that rather than translating), or devise a syntax that eliminates the ambiguity.  (For example, "(11)" could mean "k" and "(1)(1)" could be "aa".)  Or, simply say that the longest match wins, and it'll always be interpreted as "k".  (Which also means that "111" is always "ka", never "ak".)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
String text = number.replace("1", "a").replace("2","b").replace("6","f").replace("11","k");
```

By this:

```
 String text = number.replace("11","k").replace("1", "a").replace("2","b").replace("6","f");
```

Right now, the first replace you're doing: ("1", "a")
is invalidating the last one: ("11","k")

Comment: Thank you. It's that easy. I feel like a fool. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm so happy when it works. But if I have "aa", it must be "11" too. So, how to distinguish "11" for "aa" and for "k"?

Comment: I assume you are trying to establish a correspondence between two texts, based on a transformation function. That transformation function should not be ambiguous. So, you should establish if 11 corresponds to k OR aa. Both transformation should not be valid at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This failed because the `replace("1", "a")` replaced *both* `1`s with `a` characters.  The quickest fix is to perform the `replace` of all the double-digit numbers first, so there are no more double-digit numbers left when the single-digit numbers get replaced.

```
String text = number.replace("11","k").replace("1", "a").
                     replace("2","b").replace("6","f");
```

Comment: This is gonna break when a converted string is 'aa...' and not 'k...'.

Comment: There are spaces between all letters, so it would be "a a" and it would still work.

Comment: @rgettman In that case, I'd like to remove my down vote, but stackoverflow won't allow me until you make some edits to this answer.

Comment: @rgettman I'm so happy because it works. Somehow, I think what **user2793390** said must be figured out. How it ("11" for "aa" or "k") can be solved?

Comment: @Speaky If you're not gonna have spaces between every letter(unlike in your question), you cannot store numbers as strings. I already posted a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse the replacement:

```
String text = number.replace("11","k").replace("2","b").replace("6","f").replace("1","a");
```

Simplest solution IMO.
When adding other numbers, first replace these with two digits, then these with one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to store the number as an array of ints. Otherwise, there is no way of knowing if 11 is aa or k. I would create a Map and then loop over the characters in the String. You could have one map for char-to-int and one for int-to-char.

```
Map<Character,Integer> charToIntMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
charToIntMap.put('a',1);
charToIntMap.put('b',2);
charToIntMap.put('f',6);
charToIntMap.put('k',11);

Map<Integer,Character> intToCharMap = new HashMap<Integer,Character>();
intToCharMap.put(1,'a');
intToCharMap.put(2,'b');
intToCharMap.put(6,'f');
intToCharMap.put(11,'k');

String testStr = "abfk";
int[] nbrs = new int[testStr.length()];


for(int i = 0; i< testStr.length(); i++ ){
    nbrs[i] = charToIntMap.get(testStr.charAt(i));
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int num : nbrs){
    sb.append(num);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());


//Reverse
sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<nbrs.length; i++){
    sb.append(intToCharMap.get(nbrs[i]));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```